# Using MessagePack protocol in the context of serverless Azure SignalR services

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, msgpack, azure-signalr

The following code works fine with my Azure SignalR Services (serverless mode) and I am able to receieve messages/events successfully.

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(connectionInfo.NegotiationUrl!, options =>
            {
                options.Headers.Add("x-ms-signalr-userid", "myuserid");
                options.Headers.Add("x-functions-key", "mykey");
            })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5) })
            .Build();
        connection.Closed += excecption =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        connection.On("onMsg", (Action<object>)(message =>
        {
                    Console.WriteLine(message)
        }));
```

I referenced the [.NET MessagePack NuGet package for SignalR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack/6.0.12) and invoked `.AddMessagePackProtocol()` extension method in the hub connection builder per the code below but stop receiving messages from SignalR.

```cs
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(connectionInfo.NegotiationUrl!, options =>
            {
                options.Headers.Add("x-ms-signalr-userid", "myuserid");
                options.Headers.Add("x-functions-key", "mykey");
            })
                        .AddMessagePackProtocol()
            .WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5) })
            .Build();
```

Am I missing anything in this configuration? What is the right approach to solve this problem? I don't think if we need to do anything on Azure SignalR Service configuration to start getting messagePack packets.

I expect to receive the signalR messages when the message pack protocol is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chosen Azure signalR service transport type is `Persistent`, and the messagePack protocol is not supported in this mode per [this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/management-sdk-guide.md#summary-of-serialization-behaviors-of-the-arguments-in-messages).